# How to use spring-roo entities from Eclipse RCP/RAP project

Tags: eclipse, spring, aspectj, spring-roo, eclipse-rap

I have created a domain model using spring-roo, which makes heavy use of Spring and AspectJ. My model is deploying nicely as a OSGi bundle, and from the Spring STS (eclipse-based) IDE, I can call the entity classes, etc.

I need to access these domain classes from a Eclipse RCP/RAP application, and this project I keep in the normal Eclipse IDE for RCP/RAP development (i.e. it has all the PDE tools). I also added the STS and AspectJ plugins.

I added my domain bundle to the target platform, and made my Eclipse RAP app dependent on it. When I run the RAP application, I can see that my domain bundle is deployed in OSGi (i.e. it is ACTIVE). I also see that it exists in the PDE editor when I added the dependency.

However, when I try to import and use any of the domain classes, I get nothing. I can't even see the domain packages from my Java file editor.

I have tried to add a AspectJ and Spring nature to my RAP project, but still nothing.

Also, when running the Eclipse RAP application, everything deploys fine, except the RAP application, which throws the following exception:

> Mar 2, 2010 2:44:58 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
>   INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from URL [bundleentry://168.fwk1096264275/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]
>   Exception in thread "SpringOsgiExtenderThread-2" java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:171)
>       at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.close(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:345)
>       at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.fail(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:401)
>       at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.stageOne(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:287)
>       at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.refresh(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:175)
>       at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:175)
>       at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.activator.ContextLoaderListener$2.run(ContextLoaderListener.java:718)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:637)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Small update: seems Maven3/Tycho might be the answer. Will investigate and update this question if applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try not to build Roo project to jar, but reference this project from your RCP project.